# Why is Microsoft Security Essentials suddenly not appearing in the tray?

Tags: windows-xp, virus, microsoft-outlook-2003

XP SP3

My computer suddenly shut down immediately after booting and me launching Vbuzzer (my phone) and Outlook 2003. 
I have made no changes to the machine and it has worked well for months.

When I rebooted I noticed that MSE was not in the tray. I went to my programs and clicked it. It seemed to launch or at least the window came up. However, it is not in the tray and I'm not sure it booted as it used to do.

I scanned with MSE and found no virus, but I am spooked.

Can anyone suggest what may have happened and is there a fix?

Thanks.

EDIT: I was going to remove this, but it may be of value to others so I will leave it unless there are objections.

EDIT 2: I believe this is related to rootkit viruses I had: Mal/Generic - L and Mal/Generic - S. I found the free virus scanner SOPHOS http://www.sophos.com/en-us/. So much is better including speed.

Comment: I have seen this behavior in XP and windows 7, rebooting a few times cures it, as you have found out. Sometimes opening MSE from the start menu will cause the tray icon to appear, its running in task manager, it just does not load the tray icon for some reason.

Comment: @Moab: Please see edit.

Comment: So which Sophos product did you use?

Comment: Sorry. Virus removal tool: http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/virus-removal-tool.aspx

Comment: I believe this closed question is also a symptom: http://superuser.com/questions/494160/outlook-2003-crashing-again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always uninstall and reinstall.

Before you do that you may want to check msconfig under services and verify that Microsoft AntiMalware Service is still checked and running.

Comment: Thanks. I re-booted a few more times and suddenly it's there again. I'll remove the question in about an hour to give you a chance to see this.

Answer (score 2):

In the **Task and Start Menu Properties** dialog click on the **Customize** button and check to see what the MSE icon's `Behavior` is set to be. If it's "Always hide" or "Hide when inactive" that that could cause it to disappear -- and if so, change it to "Always show" if you want.

Comment: Looks good but not applicable in my case. Thanks.